# Derive a recurrence relation with initial conditions for the sequence of hexagonal numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

["hexagonal diagrams”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQy9p.png)
(diagrams for n = 1, 2, 3, 4 in picture)

Let H(n) be the n-th hexagonal number, which is given by the number of dots in the n-th hexagonal diagram. For example, H(1) = 1, H(2) = 6, and H(3) = 15.

Derive a recurrence relation with initial conditions for H(n).

I know that the hexagonal numbers can be derived using the formula: H(n) = n(2n-1) for the n-th hexagonal number however I am unsure of how to find a recurrence relation.

Comment: For reference, the hexagonal numbers appear as sequence [A000384](https://oeis.org/A000384) on OEIS. They also have a Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_number

Comment: For each n-th iteration, how many dots have each new side? How many are shared by two sides? How many new sides?

Answer (score 1):

Examine the diagrams to see how many dots are added to get from the diagram for $H_n$ to the diagram for $H_{n+1}$. They’re all added in the outermost hexagon. If we label the sides $1$ through $6$ counterclockwise, starting with the side rising up and to the left from the common vertex of the hexagons, we can see that side $1$ gets one new dot. Side $2$ gets that dot plus $n$ more. One of those $n$ dots is also on side $3$, and then there are $n$ more dots on side $3$. Keep going, and you’ll get an expression for $H_{n+1}-H_n$ in terms of $n$, which you can rearrange to get the desired recurrence. I’ve left the details in the spoiler-protected block below.

> To get the diagram for $H_{n+1}$ from the diagram for $H_n$, you add one dot at the upper right corner, then you add $n$ dots $4$ times, so you add altogether $4n+1$ dots. Thus, $H_{n+1}=H_n+4n+1$.